# Place text between two tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, pgfornament

How can I type my text between two tikzpicture environments? When I type my text, the second  tikzpicture go to next page! What I should to do?

Thanks so much

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = .8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}};

    \node[below right,rotate=270] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm, color = MidnightBlue,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 0.8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=v]{15}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    I want to type my text here but the second tikzpicture go to next page! What I should to do?

    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=Maroon,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \node[minimum size=\linewidth](vecbox){}; 
    \node[anchor=north west] at (vecbox.south west)
    {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{9}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package ornaments are inserted as a `node` in the `tikzpicture` environment with the `remember picture` and `overlay` options. 
These two options allow you to memorize the different images and make, for example, an arrow that goes from one figure to another. 
That's why there are two compilations.

As you have inserted these images as a `node`, their placement is governed by the options available on these nodes *(see section 17.5 `Positioning Nodes` in TikZ manual 3.1.4)*. Its color `color =LimeGreen` is governed by the color options of the nodes.

TikZ predefines a `node` that corresponds exactly to the entire page *(see section 17.13.2 `Referencing the Current Page Node - Absolute Positioning` in TikZ manual 3.1.4)*. 
Here, I positioned this `node` at the *bottom left* of the page (i.e. at its *South West*: `at (current page.south west)`) and anchored it to the `South West`, i.e. the image is hung on the page from its `southwest` corner: `anchor=south west`.

```
 \node[anchor=south west,color =LimeGreen] at (current page.south west)
    {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{9}};
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = .8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}};

    \node[below right,rotate=270] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm, color = MidnightBlue,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 0.8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=v]{15}
    };
%    \end{tikzpicture}



%    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=Maroon,
%    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
%    \node[minimum size=\linewidth](vecbox){}; 
    \node[anchor=south west,color =LimeGreen] at (current page.south west)
    {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{9}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 

        I want to type my text here but the second tikzpicture go to next page! What I should to do?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. no I want first tikzpicture place in top, my text same place and second tikzpicture at bottom and left

Comment: Like this one ?

Answer (score 2):

There are packages especially for such purposes, with one of them being `eso-pic`. On benefit is that they help to avoid spurious spaces, another benefit is that you can have these ornaments on all pages of the document. If you only want them on one specific page, use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{...}` on that page (and drop the `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` in the preamble).

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = .8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm,
        color = MidnightBlue]{15}};

    \node[below right,rotate=270] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm, color = MidnightBlue,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=h,symmetry=v]{15}
        \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 0.8cm,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        symmetry=v]{15}
    };
    \node[anchor=south west,color = MidnightBlue] at 
    (current page.south west)    {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{9}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{document}
I want to type my text here but the second tikzpicture go to next page! What I
should to do?
\end{document}
```

[image]